# Alinhamento correto

Tags: html, css

Boa noite a todos colegas.. Estou pesquisando muito e não consigo achar uma solução para o seguinte problema. 
Não consigo manter alinhado de nada como mostra a figura abaixo:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Baixei vários modelos mas nenhum deu certo . Ou as fotos ficam iguais a primeira linha ou a primeira linha fica igual a segunda. Alguém poderia me orientar?
Obs: o site somente fotos e 1 formulário
Obrigado

Comment: Já tentou fazer o seu próprio? Bootstrap tem muita coisa pronta pra te ajudar nisso ai. Se não quiser usar framework tem o grid e o flexbox do css.

Comment: Fizeram pra mim e eu achei que focou cheio de espaços.. e o meu site desejado é largo .. Eu não sei alterar as medidas no bootstrap.. Acabei perdendo tudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o ***[flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)*** para fazer o que deseja. Basicamente, criamos um *layout* com duas linhas (`row`s) e dentro delas colocamos os nossos blocos.

Para que os blocos quebrem conforme o tamanho da tela do usuário diminua, basta aplicar um `flex-wrap: wrap` nas `row`s, que estão como `display: flex` para que o *layout* se ajuste.

No caso, vamos aplicar a propriedade em questão dentro de um [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/@media), já que só queremos que o efeito seja aplicado quando a tela tiver tamanho igual ou inferior a `500px`.

Algo assim:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: dashed 1px #000;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.main-photo {
  width: 70%;
}

.form {
  width: 30%;
}

.photo-1,
.photo-2 {
  width: 50%;
}

/**
 * Todas as regras especificadas dentro da media query a seguir serão aplicadas
 * para dispositivos de tela menor ou igual a 500px.
 */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .row {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .main-photo,
  .form,
  .photo-1,
  .photo-2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <div class="row">
    <section class="main-photo">Foto Principal</section>
    <section class="form">Formulário</section>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <section class="photo-1">Foto 1</section>
    <section class="photo-2">Foto 2</section>
  </div>
</main>
```

Para testar o exemplo acima, clique em <kbd>Executar</kbd>, depois em <kbd>Página Toda</kbd> e vá diminuindo o tamanho da janela até alcançar `499` pixels ou menos.

---

*Flexbox* pode parecer complicado, mas é bem simples. Você só terá que estudar um pouco as suas propriedades. Recomendo alguns guias:

- https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceitos_Basicos_do_Flexbox

Comment: Fiz conforme orientou. No modo desktop 100% - fica ok. Parabens -  Mas se eu variar o tamanho da tela ; (pelo resizer) o formulário e as fotos ficam sobrepondo sobre as imagens da esquerda. No celular deitado, acontece a mesma coisa. No celular em pé, fica normal

Comment: Pode criar um [Codepen](https://codepen.io) para demonstrar esse comportamento?

Comment: Resolvido. Era só deixar as imagens responsivas .

Comment: Beleza. Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema, clique no ✔︎ ao canto superior esquerdo da postagem.